# Print result at the end of mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written this command into robomongo:

```
db.FinalLocation.find({UserName: null}).forEach(
function (obj)
{
    db.tempColl.save(obj)
});
```

Now, I want to know how many documents Have been found into **FinalLocation** collection and how many documents Have been inserted into **tempColl** collection?
I know by `db.tempColl.count()` can find but I want, at the end of my script appear something like this:

**Total empty object : 36** ---> at FinalLocation

**Total inserted object : 36** ---> at tempColl

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem:
this is my code:

```
var result = db.FinalLocation.find({UserName: null}).toArray()
print("Total empty object: "+ result.length);

var t = db.tempColl.insertMany(result);
print("Total inserted  object: "+ t.insertedIds.length);
```

This outPut:

```
Total empty object: 36
Total inserted  object: 36
```